# Return result when using Deep Link to open another app

Tags: android

I have 2 Apps, A & B. In App A, i open an activity of App B using Deep Link and via `startActivityForResult()`, but when in set result code in App B and return, App A just received `RESULT_CANCELED`! My first question is "Is it possible to return result when using Deep Link to open another app?", and if yes, where is my mistake?!

My manifest, in App B:

```
<activity android:name=".activity.TargetActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "http://www.example.com/gizmos” -->
        <!-- note that the leading "/" is required for pathPrefix-->
        <data
            android:host="www.example.com"
            android:pathPrefix="/gizmos"
            android:scheme="http" />
        <data
            android:host="www.example.com"
            android:pathPrefix="/gizmos"
            android:scheme="https" />
        <data
            android:host="example.com"
            android:pathPrefix="/gizmos"
            android:scheme="http" />
        <data
            android:host="example.com"
            android:pathPrefix="/gizmos"
            android:scheme="https" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

In App A:

```
            Uri webpage = Uri.parse("android-app://com.vancosys.payment/http/www.example.com/gizmos?name=FMarket&id=4231");

            Intent webIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, webpage);

            // Verify it resolves
            PackageManager    packageManager = getPackageManager();
            List<ResolveInfo> activities     = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(webIntent, 0);
            boolean           isIntentSafe   = activities.size() > 0;

            // Start an activity if it's safe
            if (isIntentSafe)
            {
                // '4231' is my request code
                startActivityForResult(webIntent, 4231);
            }
```

Also:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if(requestCode == 4231)
    {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            String id = data.getStringExtra("ID");

            Intent i = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("RESULT", true);
            i.putExtra("ID", id);
            startActivity(i);
        }
        else
        {
            // It JUST equals to RESULT_CANCELED!!!
            Intent i = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("result", false);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, in App B:

```
                        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
                        {
                            public void run()
                            {
                                Intent i = new Intent();
                                TargetActivity.this.setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
                                i.putExtra("ID", "45651232");
                                finish();
                            }
                        }, 3000);
```

UPDATE:
`Intent data` in `onActivityResult()` is `null`!!!

Comment: Is there a resolution for your question?

Answer (score 0):

Change your App B code like this :

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
                    {
                        public void run()
                        {
                            Intent i = new Intent();
                            i.putExtra("ID", "45651232");
                            //setResult() method should be called after all the putExtra() methods
                            TargetActivity.this.setResult(RESULT_OK, i);

                            finish();
                        }
                    }, 3000);
```

what your initial code is doing is that you are setting the "ID" extra after setting the result. You should do that before the setResult() method. Otherwise the changes in the intent will not affect the Result. **First set the Extra values to the Intent then use the setResult() method.**

Comment: Nope! Not worked. Returned intent is null and result code is RESULT_CANCELED yet...

Comment: Check whether this handler is bring invoked... Check for any possibilities where the App B can be closed without setting the Result

Answer (score 0):

Put below Intent Filter in Manifest file for activity in which you are using "onActivityResult" Method, then you can able to receive data from Othe App.

```
<intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
     <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>
```

Hope this Helps you

Comment: Nope, I still have `data == null` in my `onActivityResult()`.